# Cross-Browser Canvas using nodeJS no signature found for the function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas

I'm trying to build a canvas on a page which updates itself whenever a user draws something on it. However it looks as if the following piece of code ( from index.html) is causing an error

```
  socket.on("drawn_complete",function(data){
    ctx.putImageData(data.image,0,0);
    console.log("Everthing worked technically");
});
```

Here is the error that gets outputted in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided
```

my data.image is what gets returned from the following code:

```
ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100); // ctx is canvas.getContext("2d")
```

Here is my canvas in my html:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Here is the full nodeJS:

```
    var http = require("http")
var server = http.createServer(handler).listen(1337);
console.log("Server created at 127.0.0.1:1337");
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);


function handler(req,res)
{
    console.log("Client Connected");
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World");
}


io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    socket.on("drawing",function(data){
        var image = data["image"];
        io.sockets.emit("drawn_complete",image);
    });
});
```

Drawing is emmited when the user holds and moves the mouse inside my canvas:

Here is the code:

```
  c.onmousedown = function(evt){
moving = true
};
c.onmousemove = function(evt){
    if(moving == true)
    {
        console.log("holding and moving");

        var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
        var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
        socket.emit("drawing",{"image": ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100)});

    }
};
c.onmouseup = function(evt){
    moving = false;
};
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the enitre script:

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1337");
socket.on("drawn_complete",function(data){
    ctx.putImageData(data.image,0,0);
    console.log("Everthing worked technically");
});


var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var moving = false;
console.log(c);
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
c.onmousedown = function(evt){
moving = true
};
c.onmousemove = function(evt){
    if(moving == true)
    {
        console.log("holding and moving");

        var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
        var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
        socket.emit("drawing",{"image": ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100)});

    }
};
c.onmouseup = function(evt){
    moving = false;
};
};



</script>
```

**UPDATE**
As Palanik suggested I have trieed to serialize the image before emitting it:

```
 var stringfy = JSON.stringify(ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100));
        socket.emit("drawing",{"image": stringfy});
```

It looks as if the console does still throw the same error

**UPDATE ( 2 )**
As @Palanik suggested I tried to serialise the object. I know the following code is not exactly what he recommended however I just want to highlight something very peculiar:

*Sender:*

```
var stringfy = ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100);
        console.log(stringfy)
        var sent = JSON.stringify(stringfy);
        socket.emit("drawing",{"image": sent});
```

*Reciever*

```
socket.on("drawn_complete",function(data){
imageData = JSON.parse(data.image);
console.log(imageData);
ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
console.log("Everthing worked technically");
```

});

The interesting bit here is that the console.log of imageData prints out an oject with the same exact properties that ImageData has. Height, Width and raw. Take a look here:

```
{"height":100,"width":200,"data":{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5 etc... }
```

So as I can see from here I am able to get the object back. If I was in java a cast would be  enough;

```
ImageData object = (ImageData) imageData // Is there a way to do this?
```

Comment: On the client, how are you initializing the `ctx` of the canvas?

Comment: @jibsales ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. WHERE are you initializing? It could have something to do with the socket not being ready yet.

Comment: @jibsales I have included the entire script. Check updates

Comment: @bula when you do updates you don't have to write in bold: **Update #** and put the same code again with a few changes. You can edit your previous text and keep a clean question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution here is to use `canvas.toDataURL();`.

This will return a Base64-encoded image-string (with MIME-Type and encoding in the head).

```
var canvas = getMyCanvas(),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    encodedImageData = canvas.toDataURL(),
    image = new Image();

image.src = encodedImageData;
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h...);
```

You can pass these encoded strings to and from the server, happily.
You can use them in regular HTML `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">`, as well.

Also, you can pass `toDataURL` a couple of arguments:

```
 canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);`
```

Where, the first argument is the requested file type, and the second is the requested image-quality level (between 0 and 1).

There is no guarantee that any browser is going to support what you asked for, though, and you might just get a .png file back, anyway (which is likely what you'd want for a game, for transparencies, regardless).

Also, the Android 2.2 browser and lower, and IE9, and I think Mobile Safari 5.1 (original iPads), don't support `.toDataURL`.
I might be wrong about the iPads, but they don't support other HTML5 APIs which are useful in conjunction.

Comment: Yet again an amazing and in depth answer. Thank you

Comment: Sorry. I thought that accepting the answer offers you the bounty. I have awarded you the bounty.Sorry for that

Comment: Why use the `toDataURL` trick? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images mentions that "You can use another <canvas> element as your image source.".

Comment: @cherouvim If you read the code included in the question, what you'll see is that it's being piped through WebSockets. This is certainly not a consideration for everyone; using a canvas or an image as the source for a draw operation on another canvas is totally fine...  ...except when you're trying to update *everyone's* canvas, when **you** make an edit, via WebSockets. Or perhaps you want to persist state through cloud-saving... There are lots of reasons behind this; they just aren't `drawImage( )` specific.

Answer (score 2):

ImageData may not be portable. Try serializing imagedata before sending and deserialize and create imagedata on the receiving end.

=== Update ===

Something like :

### Sender

```
canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100)}
myData = {
        height : canvasData.height,
        width : canvasData.width,
        raw : canvasData.data
};
socket.emit("drawing",{"image": myData});
```

### Receiver

```
imgData = ctx.getImageData(myData.width, myData.height);
for (var i = 0; i < myData.raw.length) {
        imgData.data[i] = myData.raw[i];
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

This is untested code. Just an idea for you to try it out.

Comment: Not Stringify imagedata. Create new obj with width, height and pixeldata serialize it. Later create new ImageData from width, height & pixeldata.

Comment: How can I serialize an object in javascript? All I could find was stringify

Comment: I just thought you might be interested in my update since I find it really strange. I think your code will result in the same thing if I'm not wrong?

Comment: I have tried it. It results in this:                            Uncaught NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation. index.html:15
(anonymous function) index.html:15
EventEmitter.emit socket.io.js:633
SocketNamespace.onPacket socket.io.js:2248
Socket.onPacket socket.io.js:1930
Transport.onPacket socket.io.js:1332
Transport.onData socket.io.js:1303
websocket.onmessage